# How to receive and display and send values from Select input field to database

Tags: javascript, html, database

This a sample of the dropdowns using select that I have

```
<label class="form__label" for="country"> Country Of Residence</label>
<select id="country" class="form__input" name="country"/>
    <option value="null">Select Country</option>
    <option value="United Arab Emirates">United Arab Emirates</option>
    <option value="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
    <option value="Kuwait">Kuwait</option>
    <option value="Oman">Oman</option>
</select>
```

The value is stored in the database as a 'String'.

I would appreciate some help in understanding the best way forward for 2 things

**On Load**

The string value from the database should be the option displayed in my dropdown. And if for some reason the string value in the database does not match, then the 'Select Country' option should be displayed.

**On Change**

The selected value should be the value that's sent to the database as a String. The functionality for this is already implemented but earlier I was using a `input` of `type=text` .. So what type of changes are needed to send this value now from a select field.

I've researched on the net but the more I research the more I get confused. And most answers seem to be jQuery solutions. I am looking for some help with Vanilla Javascript. Somethings I need to get clarity on is 'Do I need to have a hidden field to store the value and send and receive from database?' ..  I am really confused with the information I've researched.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is you confusion? data value get time issue or store time issue? in which step you are confuse?

Comment: When I console.log the value it shows properly but the country is not displayed by default on load.. instead it shows just the 'Select Country' option

Comment: You can try to set any one option value as selected by default.

Comment: There's no default.. every user has already selected a country which is stored in the database. Onload that country needs to be shown as selected

Comment: User can select country at that time you can set selected att*.

Comment: can you suggest how that's done? Sorry for being a newbie but I am a bit lost.. also what you are suggesting is when user selects.. but what about onload?

Comment: Could you please type out a solution for onload and for onchange to set the value parameter in the Answers? It will help me a lot.

Comment: Check my demo and try, it's give you a value of user on change time this is use in your require place.

Comment: Thanks Kiran_Ray .. will try it out and get back soon..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of days of struggling, I am using this solution. If this is overkill and there's a simpler approach, please do share in comments.

**So I first identified the `select` element**

```
const country = document.getElementById('country');
```

**Then created a function as below**

```
const displayCountry = function() {
  //CREATE ARRAY OF ALL OPTIONS
  const optionsArray = Object.entries(country.children);
  console.log(optionsArray);
  // GET NAME OF COUNTRY FROM SELECT FIELD
  const nameOfCountry = country.getAttribute("value");
  console.log(nameOfCountry);
  // FIND OPTION WITH THE SAME COUNTRY NAME
  const option = optionsArray.find(
    (option) => option[1].value === nameOfCountry
  );
  // UPDATE OPTION FIELD BY SETTING ATTRIBUTE OF SELECTED
  option[1].setAttribute("selected", true);
  console.log(option[1]);
};
```

**It can be shortened as below**

```
const displayCountryShortened = function() {
  Object.entries(country.children)
    .find((option) => option[1].value === country.getAttribute("value"))[1]
    .setAttribute("selected", true);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Get select element value on event using pure JavaScript, Try this and get value.

```
var select_element = document.getElementById('country');
    
select_element.onchange = function() {
    var elem = (typeof this.selectedIndex === "undefined" ? window.event.srcElement : this);
    var value = elem.value || elem.options[elem.selectedIndex].value;
    alert(value);
    // your another required code set!
}​
```

Comment: @kiray_ray : Thanks for the answer.. it seems to do what you are asking it to do but my requirement is much simpler.. let me explain again... In this line `<select id="country" class="form__input" name="country value="India"/>` I have added the value as 'India' and on load I get the value from the database and it works fine.. but the dropdown display does not show India as the selected option.. It still shows 'Select Country'.. I want it to show India .. I think `<option value="India">` should have the `selected` attribute but I don't know how to do this..

Comment: I have used some logic for a solution .. can you check my answer below and let me know if it's ok.. I mean it's working but I don't know if it's the right approach..